# Using jQuery Plug-in (jquery-autosave) to an MVC 3 controller method via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, callback, autosave

My javascript/ajax inexperience is probably preventing me from bridging a gap here.  I have implemented a jQuery plugin called [jQuery-autosave](https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave).  The change event on my form control fires the method in the jquery.autosave.js file, however, it does not hit "success".  I believe this is because I cannot figure what the jquery.autosave method is looking for.

I see many postings where the subjects could be related to this one, however, I have not been able to connect the dots.

So this is the help I'm looking for...  What does the script in my View need to use this plug-in to persist the value of each input control in my form via a method (saveRespose) in my controller?  And, if it is not to much to ask, the frosting on the cake would be if you could explain how you determined what the script needed so that I can learn a little more about how this works?

The code for the jquery-autosave plugin can be found at the link above so I won't post here.  Being new to this subject matter, I'll probably need to provide more.  Please explain to me what you need.

My View script is here...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
            trigger: ["change", function () {
                var self = this;
                $("[name=save]").click(function () {
                    self.autosave();
                });
            } ],
            save: {
                method: "ajax",
                options: {
                    whatever: "This is it", 
                    url: "/Profile/saveResponse/"
                    , success: function () {
                        alert("saved!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX functionalities of the plugin are identical to those used by the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function (meaning, anything you can pass into that function can be passed into the 'ajax' method of the plugin). That said, generally you would pass a method name into the 'data' parameter of the AJAX request to let your controller handle it accordingly. This would look something like: `{ method: 'methodName' }` which jQuery essentially turns into a request like:
`yourUrl.asp?method=methodName` (assuming you're using a GET request).

Really, the plugin is just there to help you get the data from the form so you can pass it on to something else, like AJAX.